# NodeJS countdown: How do I define minutes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, countdown

Very simple question. I've got a NodeJS application using countdown (https://www.npmjs.com/package/countdown). The countdown itself works.

However, I don't know how to set it to 8 minutes?

The command is:

```
countdown( new Date(2000, 0, 1) ).toString();
```

I've tried, but I don't get it to less than 47 years. I'm new to all of this. Could anyone help? Feel like this is a very stupid question, but yeah... Yes, I've read the documentation.

**The countdown is supposed to count down 8 minutes from the moment it's run. It's not supposed to run from a fixed dated until a fixed date.**

Comment: Try: `countdown(start, end, units, max).toString()` with plain digits... Also, I'm curious as to why you're using a countdown in nodejs, I really hope you're not waiting for an expected action to have passed due to time. If so, you should probably be using a callback or some other form of ensuring another process is 'complete'

Comment: This library is designed to get the difference between 2 dates, so if the date you provide is 8 minutes ago, then you will get `8 minutes`

Comment: @user184994 I didn't provide any dates and it still works. It's meant to be count down from the moment it's started until 8 minutes past that

Comment: why not use `setTimeout` instead? `setTimeout(function() {}, 8 * 60 * 1000)`

Comment: @Relic maybe a stupid question, but how am I supposed to use plain digits to select "minutes" as unit?

Comment: @user184994 the user is supposed to see the timer. It's shown in an overview. The user has to react before the timer is over, not afterwards.

Comment: Sorry, I've read the docs now, I understand. Have a look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a `Date` object that is 8 minutes in the future.

You can create one based on the current date, and then use `setMinutes` to increase that by 8 minutes:

```js
let later = new Date();
later.setMinutes(later.getMinutes() + 8);

countdown(
    later,
    function(ts) {
      document.getElementById('pageTimer').innerHTML = ts.toHTML("strong");
    },
    countdown.HOURS|countdown.MINUTES|countdown.SECONDS);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/countdown/2.6.0/countdown.js"></script>

<span id="pageTimer"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks, but now it's not counting down anymore? It stays at 8 minutes "        let now = new Date();
        let later = new Date(now);
        later.setMinutes(later.getMinutes() + 8);
        var timeleft = countdown(now, later).toString();
        this.setStatus('In Queue (' + timeleft + ')');"

Comment: @ZenoFox What happens if you click `run code snippet` above? Seems to be working for me...

Comment: It works, however it doesn't work in the program I made. Do I have to change something so that it updates on its own?

Comment: You need to add a callback to your `countdown` function, like in my example, so that the `countdown` library knows what you want to do

Comment: Is the callback the "function(ts) {
      document.getElementById('pageTimer').innerHTML = ts.toHTML("strong");
    }"? It's supposed to be used in  "this.setStatus('In Queue (' + timeleft + ' left)');". Do I have to refresh that every time the timer changes or will it change automatically?

Comment: Yes, it's a function that will be called each second, allowing you to update your page. Bear in mind, you will also need to cancel this timer as well at some point, as it doesn't stop itself from the looks of it. Check in the docs, specifically the line `window.clearInterval(timerId);`

Comment: Could you send me a DM? I'm still not entirely sure how to proceed. Because the countdown is supposed to be given to another function. Would really appreciate it, but will understand if you don't want to.

Comment: Sorry, there are no DMs on StackExchange, and you don't have enough rep for the chat feature either...

Comment: Was referring to that. Is email possible?

Comment: I'd rather not give my email out on here, but if you ask a new question with the current issue you're having, myself or someone else would be happy to take a look?

Comment: I understand. Can only post soon and this is quite urgent tbh. Can you take a look here? https://pastebin.com/XcvGSuhG

Comment: So how about just calling `setStatus` from the callback?

Comment: "Error: ReferenceError: setStatus is not defined"

Comment: countdown(
                      later,
                      function(ts) {
                              this.setStatus('In Queue (' + timeleft + ' left)');
                      },
                      countdown.HOURS|countdown.MINUTES|countdown.SECONDS);

Comment: Try changing `function (ts) {` to `(ts) => {`, which should fix the scoping and allow you to use `this`, and change `timeleft` to `ts.tostring()`

Comment: Just did, but now it says Error: TypeError: ts.tostring is not a function. Thank you so much for helping me, you're making my day rn! :)         countdown(
                      later,
                      (ts) => {
                              this.setStatus('In Queue (' + ts.tostring() + ' left)');
                      },
                      countdown.HOURS|countdown.MINUTES|countdown.SECONDS);

Comment: My bad, that was a typo, should be `toString` not `tostring`

Comment: It's working! Thank you so much! You really made my day!

Comment: No probs. If you fancy accepting my answer that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like countdown outputs the unix epoch (time since 00:00 on the 1st of January 1970), which is 47 years (plus change) at the moment. Perhaps you're reading this unix epoch time, and not the time relative to "now" ?

Comment: Thanks, how can I set it to run from the moment it's started until 8 minutes after that?

Comment: From the documentation; 

The start / end arguments
The parameters start and end can be one of several values:

null which indicates "now".
a JavaScript Date object.
a number specifying the number of milliseconds since midnight Jan 1, 1970 UTC (i.e., the "UNIX epoch").
a callback function accepting one timespan argument.

So maybe you want 

countdown(null, end, countdown.MINUTES) where end would be null + (8 countdown.MINUTES)?